# junit test runs fine in eclipse and from the command line, but fails in gradle with noclassdeffounderror

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit, noclassdeffounderror

i have this code that has been working fine for a while on windows 8. all of a sudden, i get a no class def found error with this test:

```
package com.tayek.tablet;
import org.junit.*;
import com.tayek.tablet.io.LoggingHandler;
public class LHTestCase {
    @Test public void test() {
        LoggingHandler.init(); // this is line 6!
    }
}
```

using -verbose:class and running a single test case from the gradle command line (gradle test --tests com.tayek.tablet.LHTestCase), i see:

```
[Loaded org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$3 from file:/C:/Users/ray/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar]
[Loaded com.tayek.tablet.io.LoggingHandler from file:/D:/ray/dev/conradapps/rabbit/build/instrumented_classes/]
[Loaded com.tayek.tablet.io.LoggingHandler$MyFormatter from file:/D:/ray/dev/conradapps/rabbit/build/instrumented_classes/]
[Loaded java.util.logging.SocketHandler from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0\lib\modules\bootmodules.jimage]
```

a while later, i see:

```
[Loaded com.tayek.tablet.io.SmallerLogServerTestCase from file:/D:/ray/dev/conradapps/rabbit/build/classes/test/]

com.tayek.tablet.LHTestCase > test FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at LHTestCase.java:6
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at LHTestCase.java:6
[Loaded com.tayek.tablet.io.SocketHandlerTestCase from file:/D:/ray/dev/conradapps/rabbit/build/classes/test/]
```

so it looks like it loaded the class and then can not find it?

i have no clue why it is loading other test cases.

edit: added stacktrace:

edit: added output from reports/test:

thanks

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExec
uter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.exec
ute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execut
e(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu
ter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter
.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execut
e(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter
.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTa
skWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTa
skWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.
onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableE
xecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the rep
ort at: file:///D:/ray/dev/conradapps/rabbit/build/reports/tests/index.html
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.handleTestFailures(Test.java:1129)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:567)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 14 more
```

output from test reports/test:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.<clinit>(TouchCollector.java:40)
    at com.tayek.tablet.io.LoggingHandler.__cobertura_init(LoggingHandler.java)
    at com.tayek.tablet.io.LoggingHandler.<clinit>(LoggingHandler.java)
    at com.tayek.tablet.LHTestCase.test(LHTestCase.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:747)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:384)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:262)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: It may help to run with `--stacktrace` and post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: What is the message in `ClassNotFoundException`? What is the exact reason for loading failure?

Comment: Facing the same issue; passes w/ intellij, but failing w/ gradle. Any luck in finding the solution?